# Closed XML - Datatable and rows count

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am trying to use Closed XML in a C# ASP.NET Web application. I have a dataset which contains more than 30 data tables. I want to pass each of the data table as a separate worksheet and then create the excel.

Each data table has 10000 rows and 255 columns. 
I am getting the error :

```
    {System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.Cell(XLAddress cellAddressInRange)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.Cell(Int32 row, Int32 column)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell.SetValue[T](T value, Int32 ro, Int32 co)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell.InsertTable[T](IEnumerable`1 data, String tableName, Boolean createTable)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell.InsertTable(DataTable data, String tableName, Boolean createTable)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell.InsertTable(DataTable data)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheets.Add(DataTable dataTable, String sheetName)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheets.Add(DataTable dataTable)
```

I have tried to use the below code

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
   wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
}

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= " + filename1 + ".xlsx");

using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
   MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
   Response.Flush();
   Response.End();
}
wb.Dispose();
```

The error is happening in the line

```
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
```

The first datatable is added and then the loop moves to the second datatable. In the second instance, I am getting the error.

Is there a limit on the number of rows and columns which can be used in Closed Xml ? Also, Is there any other way to achieve this exporting data to excel ?

Comment: ClosedXML is build for easy use first, not memory usage. This means that it is not possible to work with worksheets that have millions of cells.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any other option. Also, the error is in worksheets.Add line